# Content after less than symbol (<) is getting removed inside script tag

Tags: php, html

I'm having **index.html** file, from the html file I'm trying to get content inside the script tag. Here's the script code which is inside the html file :

```
<script>
   var ssMetadata = [{ name: 'hyundai', frames: 2 }];
   for(i=0; i<ssMetadata.length; i++) {
       var new_data = ssMetadata[i].name;
   }
</script>
```

So im using **DOMDocument** class to achieve it. Here is the code :

```
    $html_file = 'index.html';
    $content = file_get_contents($html_file);

    $doc = new DOMDocument();
    $doc->loadHTML($content);

    $script_tag = $doc->getElementsByTagName('script');

    if($script_tag->length > 0) {
        foreach ($script_tag as $tag) {
            echo "<pre>"; print_r($tag); 
        }
    }
```

If I do print, I'm getting data till `<` (less than symbol from the script content). Below is the output which I'm getting.

```
DOMElement Object
(
[tagName] => script
[schemaTypeInfo] => 
[nodeName] => script
[nodeValue] => 
 var ssMetadata = [{ name: 'hyundai', frames: 2 }];
   for(i=0; i
[parentNode] => (object value omitted)
[childNodes] => (object value omitted)
[firstChild] => (object value omitted)
[lastChild] => (object value omitted)
[previousSibling] => (object value omitted)
[nextSibling] => (object value omitted)
[attributes] => (object value omitted)
[ownerDocument] => (object value omitted)
[namespaceURI] => 
[prefix] => 
[localName] => script
[baseURI] => 
[textContent] => 
 var ssMetadata = [{ name: 'hyundai', frames: 2 }];
   for(i=0; i
```

How can I get all the content inside the script tag?

Comment: I cannot edit html file as the file is being uploaded from client side @Pete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you are using a `<pre>` tag, you still need to encode special characters, specifically `<`. Change your output to:

`echo htmlentities(print_r($tag, true));`

Comment: Exactly :(.. Thank you chris.  Its helped me a lot